# Angularjs change module configuration dynamically for $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a site using angular's built in routing.  When a user logs off and another user logs in, I am changing what is visible in the menu based on that users permissions.  While this works, the configured routing still works so the user can use the browser's back function to navigate.  Also, on page load, I am dynamically loading the route information server side so angular is only aware of the routes that the user is allowed to use.  This stops the user from navigating using the browsers back function, but requires a page refresh.

**Is there anyway to change a module configuration for the $routeProvider dynamically?**

From what I have researched, the answer is no because the provider isn't available anymore when the module is run.

Comment: Thats correct you can't, but you can set hooks on state changes and verify the user credentials and perform redirections

Comment: @Dayan Moreno Leon My next step was to put a function into routeChangeStart to compare creds to the route.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to `$locationChangeStart` and stop the change if the user does not have permission. Try this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
   //if user does not have permission
       event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: That is what I have done, but my end all solution would be to re-bootstrap angular to take a new routing configuration and not perform this check client side.

Comment: @Ben Felda: I'm afraid we cannot do this. Let's see if someone can provide a solution.